# golang json doesn't parse fields with tag of embedded structure correctly

Tags: json, go, tags, field

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type InnerData struct {
    M int64 `josn:"m"`
    N int64 `json:"n"`
}

//JSONData is a json data example
type JSONData struct {
    Hello string    `json:"hello"`
    Data  InnerData `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    v := JSONData{Hello: "world", Data: InnerData{N: 100000, M: 123456}}
    mashaled, err := json.Marshal(&v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(mashaled))
}
```

Noted the field M in InnerData has a tag m, so the  expected result is :{"hello":"world","data":{"m":123456,"n":100000}}.
While I have

```
{"hello":"world","data":{"M":123456,"n":100000}}
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem, or where am I wrong?

Comment: You have a typo in your struct tag: `josn:"m"`. Change it to `json:"m"`.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake in the tag declaration with the spelling of `json` as `josn`

```
type InnerData struct {
    M int64 `josn:"m"` // the spelling is not correct for json.
    N int64 `json:"n"`
}
```

Change the tag for field M as

```
type InnerData struct {
    M int64 `json:"m"` // the spelling is not correct for json.
    N int64 `json:"n"`
}
```

One more thing is `InnerData` is not embedded struct. In Golang spec embedded struct is described as:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an
>   embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name T
>   or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not
>   be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

// A struct with four embedded fields of types T1, *T2, P.T3 and *P.T4

```
struct {
    T1        // field name is T1
    *T2       // field name is T2
    P.T3      // field name is T3
    *P.T4     // field name is T4
    x, y int  // field names are x and y
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. Sorry for the wrong declaration of embedded field. May I know how to say the Data field inside JSONData? It should be composed structure?

Comment: @MrGoogle `InnerField` will work there is no issue in that or what name you want just name the tag with that value.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your code:

In your `InnerData`, you put `josn` instead of `json`.

Fix those typos and try again.

Comment: Correct. Thanks very much.